# Possible underflow error through the usage of java.util.Date

Tags: java, java.util.date

This code:

```
package test;

import java.util.Date;

public class DateUnderflow {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Long timestamp = -8120649749785140250L;
        System.out.println(new Date(timestamp));
    }
}
```

Produces the following output:

```
"Sat Aug 03 10:00:59 CET 257325894"
```

How come? An underflow without an exception?

Doc says says the `date` parameter of `Date(long date)` is the number of milliseconds since epoch, so I'm a bit surprised to find myself that far into the future..

My setup:

- Linux mint 17.1
- Eclipse Luna Service Release 1a (4.4.1)
- java7-openjdk-amd64

Comment: Have you tried debugging this yourself?

Comment: I have the same output on Windows with Oracle JDK 7u71

Comment: "An underflow without an exception?" do you expect to see exceptions on underflow/overflow? You really shouldn't, that don't usually happen.

Comment: Same output on Arch Linux running Oracle JDK 1.8.0_31.

Comment: Funny. I'd rather expect exception to be thrown.

Comment: @eis Would you not expect `Date(long date)` to either complain (throw an exception) or return a meaningful `Date` as per doc? My point with that sentence is that it seems that the accepted input breaks the functionality silently.

Comment: @kidmose that's what overflows and underflows generally do. On the top of my head, I don't know of any case where underflow/overflow would throw an exception.

Comment: @eis Sorry if I was vague I'll give it a last try to explain my point; When a method is passed a parameter that will cause the method to fail to behave as described in the specification it should throw an exception such as [IllegalArgumentException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html) rather than silently fail.

Answer (score -1):

RTFM ([manual](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#Date(long)))

> #### `public Date(long date)`
>
> Constructs a Date object using the given
>   milliseconds time value. If the given milliseconds value contains time
>   information, the driver will set the time components to the time in
>   the default time zone (the time zone of the Java virtual machine
>   running the application) that corresponds to zero GMT.
>
> #### Parameters:
>
> date - milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT not to exceed
>   the milliseconds representation for the year 8099. A negative number
>   indicates the number of milliseconds before January 1, 1970, 00:00:00
>   GMT.

## **not to exceed the milliseconds representation for the year 8099**

---

In addition to this I am most likely saving someones time by saying: if you deal with time in java use joda time library:

http://www.joda.org/joda-time/

Comment: You're quoting [java.sql.Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#Date%28long%29) while the question pertains to [java.util.Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date%28long%29)

Comment: The reference explains why a large positive long must be expected to fail, not why a large negative long can't be expected to work.

Comment: downvoting, since the answer doesn't provide any rationale why would java.sql.Date javadoc apply to java.util.Date, especially when [java.util.Date equivalent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date%28long%29) does not mention this.

Answer (score -2):

Max long value is `9223372036854775807`. If you exceeds this max value, next value would be minimum max value.

If you construct a date out of this max long value, this will results to a date. What about a date next to that. If you add more mili-second to the next starts from minimum long value.

`-8120649749785140250` is equivalent to `9223372036854775807 + 1102722287069635559`

Try `System.out.println(9223372036854775807L+1102722287069635559L);`

I believe your code is equivalent to

```
Date d1 = new Date(9223372036854775807L); // Date for max long value
Date d2 = new Date(d1.getTime() + 1102722287069635559L); // plus some mili-seconds
System.out.println(d2);
```

This gives the result you are getting.

Comment: how does this answer the question?

Comment: I would appreciate some comment on why I am wrong along with down vote so that I can educate myself.

Comment: The min value of long is `-9223372036854775808L`. `-8120649749785140250L` is closer to 0 than this.  Incidentally, Date accepts negative numbers in its constructors (and this is required to produce dates before 1970).

Comment: If you construct a date out of this max long value, this will results to a date. What about a date next to that? How will you get that using mili-second?